# Como que eu faço um calculo matemático simples no Tkinter?

Tags: python, matemática, tkinter

Estou tentando fazer um simples calculo matemático no Python porem quando tento usar meu código não funciona

Meu código :

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import *

win = tk.Tk()

win.title("Calculadora de média v1.0")
win.configure(background="light blue")
win.geometry('600x500')
win.resizable(False, False)

#---------------#
lg = "light blue"
cd14 = "Candara 14"
#/\ variaveis para o background e fonte dos textos /\#

#\/ Widgets \/#

Texto1 = tk.Label(win,text = "Calculadora de média",background=lg,font="Candara 14")
Texto1.pack()

Texto2 = tk.Label(win,text = "Nota do Teste:",bg=lg,font=cd14)
Texto2.place(x=27,y=50)

Teste = tk.Entry(win)
Teste.place(x=150,y=55)

Media = Teste - 2
Texto3 = tk.Label(win,text = Media,bg=lg,font=cd14)

win.mainloop()
```

**O erro** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cauã Wernek\Desktop\pythonbook\calculadora de media\gui\pythongui.py", line 27, in <module>
    Media = Teste - 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Entry' and 'int'
```

Oque fiz de errado?

Comment: Batata, você está tentando subtrair 2 de um objeto (Teste - 2), isso realmente vai gerar erro, o que você pretendia com essa linha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `Teste` que você está tentando subtrair é um objeto de `Entry`, ele não é um número. Se quiser obter o valor dele, deverá invocar o método `get()` que retornará uma string e depois disso converter a mesma para `int`. Veja este simples exemplo abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *

def somar():
    global resultado
    texto = entrada_de_texto.get()
    numero = int(texto)
    resultado += numero
    print("Resultado: %i"%resultado)

janela = Tk()
resultado = 0

entrada_de_texto = Entry(janela,width=10,bg="white",font=("Arial",15))
entrada_de_texto.pack()

Button(janela,text="Somar",command=somar).pack()
janela.mainloop()
```